# address1_latitude and address1_longitude is not getting from RetrieveMultiple

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Hi i have tried to get address1_latitude and address1_longitude from CRM using CRM SDK here is mu code

```
var querybyattribute11 = new QueryByAttribute("account");
querybyattribute11.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name", "address1_city", "statuscode", "address1_postalcode", "address1_latitude", "address1_longitude");
querybyattribute11.Attributes.AddRange("name");
querybyattribute11.Values.AddRange("ASSOCIATED COMBUSTION INC");
EntityCollection entities = service.RetrieveMultiple(querybyattribute11);

foreach (Entity item in entities.Entities)
{

   // Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}. Id: {1}", role.Name, role.Id);
   list += item.Attributes["name"].ToString() + "  " + item.Attributes["address1_longitude"] .ToString() + "\n";
}
```

But I am not geting it  `item.Attributes["address1_longitude"]` 
error message is

```
'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'
```

Comment: When you debug does entities contain that column or is it null?

Comment: yes there is no attribute present in that address1_longitude name

Comment: I've not a written a query this way. I would normally do something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328149.aspx. However, I think it's because you're not adding it to your attributes range like you have done with "name".

Comment: @sr28 I have tried that method also but its not getting . Do you know we need to set any special permission in CRM for this Particular Field in order to get  it using RetrieveMultiple.

Comment: I think depending on the permissions of the user you're connecting as can determine what fields are available. However, I'm assuming your not impersonating a user or something and you're using a standard connection method, in which case it wouldn't have special permissions. It may well be null as stated by Jordi. You should really debug and check exactly what you're getting in entities.

Comment: find the field type and use GetAttributeValue http://www.crmanswers.net/2015/04/getattributevalue-demystified.html

Answer (score 1):

It might be because it's null.

Try either one of these 2 options:

```
item["address1_longitude"]  (shouldn't raise exception, it would return null if blank, otherwise the address longitude)
```

To check if the column exists:

```
item.Attributes.ContainsKey("address1_longitude")
```

Comment: Hi i actually need to get 'address1_longitude' for display in my project dont want to check whether the field is null or not . Thanks for your help . Is there any reason latitude and longitude is getting null?

Comment: It is null when it's blank basically. It doesn't have to have a value necessarily